# Grammar form of masc/fem oriented questions, 2nd singular

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

I would like to confirm that in french when asking someone about their work, nationality, etc, we direct the adjective used according to our speakers sex. Opposite of what happens in english:

"Are you French?",

"Are you tall?"

The adjective stays the same no matter who we direct the question to.

This might be a simple question, however i was unable to find a clear answer after a 15 min google search. Either it's one of those treated as "obvious", or i have searched in wrong places. Please clarify.

Comment: Note that if you don't know the sex of the target people, or if there are both male and female there, masculine must be used.

Comment: Please include examples **in French** of what you think it should be in English. And then answers can start from your examples. It does not matter if you make mistakes, they'll be rectified in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, in French, we inflect the adjectives for gender and number. This reference seemed serviceable: [Cliff's notes](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-i/french-i-adjectives/changing-masculine-to-singular-feminine) about adjectives.

Comment: Thank you for the source. Somewhat i was very wary in assuming so  due to lack of examples with specific m/f form used in "you" case. French raises so many doubts when learning!

Comment: French is more complicated than English, IMHO :-)

Comment: Un des buts de French Language est de construire [une bibliothèque la plus exhaustive possible de questions concernant le français](http://french.stackexchange.com/tour) et dans cette optique il est préférable que les réponses soient soutenues par des exemples et des explications. Par ailleurs [il est aussi recommandé](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) de ne pas se contenter de donner un lien vers une explication mais d'en donner le contenu car la page vers laquelle le lien est fait peut être appelée à disparaître.